# Azure Disk Attachment to VM using C# and StorageManagementClient/ComputeManagementClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I already had a working C# ResourceManager application that could successfully attach disks to virtual machines. However I solved this with the nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute`. But, since this package causes problems in other developments, it was decided not to use it anymore. For that we are using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent`.

Until now I had the following code (short version):

```
var computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials) {
      SubscriptionId = credentials.DefaultSubscriptionId };

var ObjVirtualMachines = computeClient.VirtualMachines.Get(resourcegroup, vmname);

ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Add(
      new DataDisk(ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count + 1,
                   "Attach", name, null, null, null, null, null,
                   new ManagedDiskParameters(resourceid, acctype)));

var newUpdatesVM = computeClient.VirtualMachines.CreateOrUpdate(
      resourcegroup, ObjVirtualMachines.Name, ObjVirtualMachines);
```

That works pretty much, but as I said I have to translate to the other package.

First I thought I can solve these problems with the `StorageManagementClient`.

But I did not get any options to update the virtual machine, because of type mismatch of the parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does  `i have to translate to the other package` mean? Could you please add more information about that?

Comment: Sure, i used the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute package, wich has is own namespace. Since this led to incompatibilities, I now have to work with the above package and therefore have a completely new namespace. But since I don't know this namespace, I thought someone would know about it, and have an idea how to implement it.

Comment: ok, cool, got it done

Comment: If it is resolved, please add it as  an answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is the answer...

```
var ObjVirtualMachines = computeClient.VirtualMachines.GetAsync(ressgroup, virtualmname, null, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Result;
var storagemanagementclient = new StorageManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = credentials.DefaultSubscriptionId };

ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Add(new DataDisk(
ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count + 1,
DiskCreateOptionTypes.Attach,
name,
null,
null,
null,
null,
new ManagedDiskParametersInner(resourceid, acctype)));

var newUpdateVM = computeClient.VirtualMachines.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ressgroup, virtualmname, ObjVirtualMachines);
```

and for the acctype use this.

```
 var computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = credentials.DefaultSubscriptionId };
 var disk = computeClient.Disks.ListAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
 var content = azure.Disks.GetById(disk.Id);
 var resourceid = disk.Id;
 var ressgroup = Resourcegroup.Get(context);
 var virtualmname = VirtualMachineName.Get(context);
 var acctype = getAccType(content.Sku.AccountType.ToString());
```

getAccType Function is this...

```
 public StorageAccountTypes getAccType(string input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "StandardLRS": return StorageAccountTypes.StandardLRS;
            case "PremiumLRS": return StorageAccountTypes.PremiumLRS;
            //    case "StandardSSDLRS":return "StandardSSD_LRS";
            //    case "UltraSSDLRS":return "UltraSSD_LRS";
            default: return StorageAccountTypes.StandardLRS;

        }
    }
```

The Problem is that the AccType version in this namespace is limited to 2 (StandardLRS and PremiumLRS) . In the old version you had 4 different versions of it.